# What are the reasons to constraint a column to be NOT NULL in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

As a newbie to databases and SQL, I wonder what are the pros (and perhaps cons) of placing the constraint NOT NULL when creating a table in SQLite.

I understand that it ensures that no NULLs can be inputed in that column, and that can be desirable. But besides that, I wonder if it improves performance of any kind -- e.g., by reducing the table's disk space or improving the speed of some queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints do not affect disk space. (In SQLite, NULL is just [another value type](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).)
A NOT NULL constraint can speed up *some* queries; for example, UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints can optimize away a DISTINCT.

However, the primary purpose of constraints is to prevent programming errors so that you can trust the database to contain correct data.

Comment: Declaring that a column can be NULL does keep additional record of whether a given row and column is NULL. In general this costs a bit or a byte per column and row, although for particular DMBSes in particular situations like the last column in a row there may be no extra storage needed.

Comment: @philipxy This question is about SQLite, where (NOT) NULL constraints do not make any difference in the record format.

Answer (score 0):

If some columns form a PRIMARY KEY then they must be NOT NULL. If they are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY then they must be a PRIMARY KEY (and NOT NULL) or UNIQUE.

NULL allows you to have a value in a column that is not one of the values of the type that it is declared with. If you don't need or want that value then you don't want it to be set to NULL.

But when a column value can be NULL, that value will never compare equal to any other value, including NULL, and the comparison result is also NULL, and that further affects the condition being evaluated. Despite what people say, this behaviour does *not* return a result as if the NULLs were somehow indicating an unknown value, a non-applicable value, or anything else. However one can write queries to specifically do so while accounting for NULL behaviour and remembering that conditions don't mean what they normally mean without NULL. This is a source of SQL errors and complexity.

You never *need* to use a NULL column. Instead of that column in the original base table typically you can have a separate base table with one or more of its keys plus just that column as NOT NULL. Having the NULL column saves JOINs sometimes but costs filtering out rows with NULLs sometimes. The NULL version has fewer total rows but the latter typically an extra bit or byte per nullable column per row.

If you just use a table without NULLs but with a NULL constraint it will add that per-column per-row space overhead. Practically speaking this is usually irrelevant. Meanwhile along with that (small) waste you are throwing away the integrity check.

So if you consciously *want* a NULL because the meaning of a column in a row of a base table includes it being a value not of its type then make it NULL and if you consciously *don't want* a NULL because the meaning of a column in a row of a base table includes it being a value only of its type then make it NOT NULL.